# Is there a maximum of emails that can be received for Gmail account? And what is it?

Tags: gmail

Is there a maximum of emails that can be received per day for a Gmail account? And if there is - what is it? Is something like 500 000 or more incoming emails possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

86,400 max limit

Here are best practices to avoid reaching the storage limit:

```
Send message logs and automated emails to Google Groups. Using Groups, you can use a web interface to read very large or frequently mailed announcements that quickly hit the receiving limits of your email account.
Avoid using a single account for multiple users, and use Google Groups for sharing mail. Map 10 or fewer email aliases per account. Use groups to create shared mailboxes or to allow many people to send and receive mail with a single address.
Subscribe to the daily digest forms of heavily trafficked email lists.
Avoid using catch-all accounts. Spammers often try to guess email addresses in your domain. When they guess incorrectly, the spam is delivered to the catch-all address. The high mail volume can quickly exceed the Gmail receiving limits.
```